# How can I prevent water damage to trim next to a bathtub?

Tags: bathtub, trim, trim-carpentry

It looks like the trim absorbed too much moisture.

[image: This trim is right next to the bathtub]

Comment: We have enough context now, but your question isn't clear. Are you asking about replacement (carpentry) or something to do with water? All my homes have trim alongside bathtubs and none look like that. Proper use of a shower curtain and good child supervision are all it really takes.

Comment: Find the leak and fix it.

Answer (score 4):

It appears to be caused by mopping the floor with a wet string mop. You will need to keep it dry, this is a precursor to mold. Using a plastic trim could possibly solve the problem as it will tolerate some moisture.  Plastic worked great in my basement. You could mist it with hydrogen peroxide or vinegar to kill what mold is there, much safer then bleach.